# 3D game engine scriptable in lua

Tags: 3d, games, engine, lua

I searched for 3D game engine scriptable in lua language. I found some where cafu engine is looks good. What is the best and frequently used 3D game engine(lua language)

I found a post here for 3D game engine where openscenegraph and OGRE were mentioned. But both are c++ not lua scriptable. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't mean to sound rude or ignorant but maybe you should post you question here since most of the guys here will not have a clue about what you are asking:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Just saying...

Answer (score 0):

Roblox Studio. It might sound stupid, but Roblox Studio uses Lua and is actually quite advanced. The only problem is you can only upload the games to Roblox unless there is some sort of way you can export the .rbxl files as something else. I highly doubt you want to publish your game on Roblox. That's how I first learned (and still learning!) Lua though.